# How to call Activity method from Presenter in Clean architecture?

Tags: java, android, clean-architecture

I am developing an app where I am using clean architecture. In presenter, when something comes to method onCompleted then I must call function from Main activity.
this is my Presenter:

```
public class CheckInPresenter implements Presenter {

    UseCase postCheckInUseCase;
    Context context;

    @Inject
    CheckInPresenter(@Named("putCheckIn") UseCase postCheckInUseCase){
        this.postCheckInUseCase = postCheckInUseCase;
    }

    public void initialize(){this.initializeCheckIn();}
    public void initializeCheckIn(){this.putCheckIn();}
    public void putCheckIn(){
        this.postCheckInUseCase.execute(new CheckInSubscriber());

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
    private final class CheckInSubscriber extends DefaultSubscriber<EventEntity>{
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

            Log.d("onCompleted", "OnCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("onError", "OnError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(EventEntity eventEntity) {

            Log.d("onNext", "OnNext");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my function from MainActivity that I have to call:

```
public void getDataForToolbar() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.Account_json), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String account = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json), null);

        if (account != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            mAccount = gson.fromJson(account, AccountModel.class);

            for (CompanyModel com : mAccount.getCompanies()) {
                String name = com.getName();
                company_name.setText(name);
                logo_url = com.getLogo_url();
            }
            if (logo_url == null || logo_url.isEmpty()) {
                Picasso
                        .with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.default_company)
                        .resize(70, 58)
                        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(8, 0))
                        .into(toolbarImage);
            } else {
                picassoLoader(this, toolbarImage, logo_url);
            }
            String username = mAccount.getUsername();
            if(mAccount.getStatus()){
                aUsername.setText(username + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.on_duty));
                aUsername.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorGreen));
            }else{
                aUsername.setText(username + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.off_duty));
                aUsername.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorWhite));
            }

        }
    }
```

Could someone helps me how to call this function into my onCompleted method in Presenter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some Activity's function from another object, you'll have to pass Activity's reference to that object. This means that you need to add Activity parameter to presenter's constructor.

**Side note**

I know that what you're implementing is called a "clean architecture" in many places (including the official MVP tutorials by Google), but you might want to read my posts on the subject in order to get an alternative view on what "clean" on Android should look like.

[Why activities in Android are not UI elements](http://www.techyourchance.com/activities-in-android-are-not-ui-elements/)

[MVC and MVP architectural patterns in Android](http://www.techyourchance.com/mvc-and-mvp-architectural-patterns-in-android-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create interface IView and make your Activity to implement it.
In IView create method `void getDataForToolbar();`

I see `@Inject` annotation in your `CheckInPresenter`, so if you are using Dagger 2, update you Dagger module's constructor with IView, create a provider method for it and provide it for `CheckInPresenter` in this module.

Place `IView` in constructor of `CheckInPresenter` and update provider method for `CheckInPresenter` in Dagger module and Dagger component initialization in your `Activity`.

For example, it might look like this:

```
public class YourActivity implements IView {
    ...
}

@Module
public class YourModule {

    private IView view;

    public YourModule(IView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Provides 
    public IView provideView() {
        return view;
    }

    @Provides 
    @YourScope
    public Presenter providePresenter() {
        return new YourPresenter(view);
    }
}
```

Just complete your existing Presenter and Module with IView.
After that call in your `onCompleted` method `view.getDataForToolbar()`.